# How to add stack-level tags to cloudformation stack deployed using SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to add tags to a stack while using SAM deploy, but they're not showing up.
The SAM cli command code can be found below.

```
sam deploy --stack-name test-stack --resolve-image-repos --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --no-fail-on-empty-changeset --template-file ./.aws-sam/build/template.yaml --resolve-s3 --tags Name=test-stack az:zone=infra
```

Tags are not being created in the CloudFormation stack despite giving the —tag parameter to the cli.

Can someone tell me how to add stack-level tags to the CloudFormation stack that is deployed using SAM CLI?

Comment: Maybe that was a bug in a specific version or a small problem in your setup but for me this worked fine, following [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-config.html).

Notice that you have to put quotes around tags, ie. `--tags "Name=test-stack az:zone=infra"`

Answer (score 6):

I'll rather suggest to put them in the `samconfig.toml` file, like:

```
[default.deploy.parameters]
stack_name = "your-application"
s3_bucket = "your-s3-for-cloudformation-stuff"
s3_prefix = "your-folder-name"
...
tags = "Name=\"test-stack\" az:zone=\"infra\""
```

That will propagate tags down to all the resources of the stack (including CloudFormation stack itself)

Comment: Just a note - it doesn't look like the tags value supports normal TOML key-values either, so you have to do them with the above format.

Comment: Worked for me! Mine would be `tags = "project=\"my-apps\""`. Thanks!